# Phase lag changes cross spectrum

Tags: cross-correlation, digital-filters

I have a same noise passing through two different ARMA filter. The autospectrum of first filter is given by S11=G1*G1*S_in where S_in is input spectrum created by set of random numbers.

Similarly the autospectrum of second filter is given by S22=G2*G2*S_in where S_in is input spectrum created by same set of random numbers as the previous one.

The cross spectrum that i expect is S12=G1*G2*S_in.But the amplitude is reduced is this due to phase shift of the filter or the derivation above is incorrect.

Attached is an image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWrAb.jpg) explaining the above statements.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Derivation seems to be wrong. I am guessing from derivation that it is power spectral density that you are talking about. Your derivation seems to be wrong, cross density would be $$S_{xy}(x)S_in=G1(x)G2\times(G2^*)(x)S_in$$ or $$S_{yx}(x)S_in=G1\times(G1^*)(x)G2(x)S_in.$$ If you take magnitude spectrum both will be same, phase spectrum will be of 180 shift.